# How to pass a variable to the os.chdir() method?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to pass `location = "C:\Program Files (x86)\DATAQ Instruments\1100\5F80861A\Testing 04-28-2021"` to the `os.chdir()` method but I'm getting the following error:

```
os.chdir(location)
```

**OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\DATAQ InstrumentsH0\x05F80861A\Testing 04-28-2021'**

I've also tried using the using the string format method for passing the variable.

```
os.chdir(r"{}".format(location))
```

But still getting the same error.

Any suggestions to solve this?

One of the answers suggested to use `location = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\DATAQ Instruments\1100\5F80861A\Testing 04-28-2021"` which worked but please see the update below.

Update:
I want to mention that I'm going to sys.argv method to get the location variable using the terminal. So I'm concerned about how would I set the location variable as a raw string in my code.

I saw a post on converting string to raw string by doing the following:

```
location = "C:\Program Files (x86)\DATAQ Instruments\1100\5F80861A\Testing 04-28-2021"
location = location.encode('unicode_escape')
```

> b'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\DATAQ
> InstrumentsH0\x05F80861A\\Testing 04-28-2021'

Now if I pass the location to os.chdir() it still gives me the same error.

Comment: Try to define location as row strings `location = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\DATAQ Instruments\1100\5F80861A\Testing 04-28-2021"`

Comment: `location.encode('unicode_escape')` - no, no, escape the backslashes in the string when you write it, don't put unicode special characters into the string and then hope that `unicode_escape` will replace them with escape sequences that coincidentally match what the string is supposed to be. Use ``\\`` to escape a backslash in a string literal, or write `r"..."` so that ``\`` means a literal ``\`` character.

Comment: *"One of the answers suggested to use location = ... which worked"* So you received a correct answer, but then changed the question so that it was no longer correct. That is not how to use Stack Overflow; if you have a correct answer then mark it as accepted, and if you have another question then ask it separately.

Answer (score 1):

In your path you have some unicode characters which are `\1100\5`

you can directly use raw string while defining location like

```
location = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\DATAQ Instruments\1100\5F80861A\Testing 04-28-2021"
print(os.chdir(location))
```

Comment: Your updated question indicates you *haven't done* what this answer suggests you do, you did something completely different (and which doesn't work). This answer doesn't need to be changed in light of your update.

Comment: @kaya3 I did what this answer suggests. And very bold of you to assume that I didn't try what they suggested. That being said, the answer came minutes after posting my after which don't usually happen in my case, so that's why it took time to update the question.

Comment: No, your updated question clearly shows that you did not. Perhaps you did not understand this answer; it looks like you saw the words "raw string" and then went away to search for how to convert to a raw string and found the wrong thing to do in the wrong context.

Comment: @MajorMajorMajorMajor declare `location` variable with `r'your location string'`, please use `r` before string and try again. you can copy paste these two lines as it is from my answer